# Creating a clustered index on this heap?

Tags: sql, clustered-index

So I am curious to know if it is worth creating a clustered index on a heap table that has about 30M rows of data. Before now, it wasn't going to be used in any application that we have but now we are creating an app to query that table.

The reason why I ask if it is worth it is because the application we are creating is basically doing this type of query.

```
SELECT *
FROM [table];
```

I am leaving the * in to represent that we are basically pulling all fields.

So my question is, is it worth creating a clustered index on a table that does not have one even though we are going to be selecting all fields and rows for our application?

Thanks for any info/advice.

Comment: Hang on... you're always going to ask for all 30M rows, every time..?

Comment: Selecting 30 million rows from a heap table for application use is possibly the worst thing that you can be doing. There is a lot of considerations for how to handle that much data. This question would be best suited for [dba.se]

Comment: I wouldn't want an app to retrieve all 30 mio rows to the client. What are you doing with the data, display it to the user?

Comment: You're saying SQL (= query language), but I assume that you really mean **SQL Server** - right? Please use the `sql-server` tag to make this clear! And please also specify the **version** (2005, 2008, 2012) you're using!

Answer (score 1):

No it is not worth it. If you are going to run a `select` without a `where` clause, a clustered index will just add more data to the Page files, depending on what you choose for your index(It all really depends on your data). Creating a larger scan of the table.  A Heap table is the actual better performance wise in many situations(if you are just getting all rows from a table and not using joins/wheres/filter clauses of some sort), because it is stored in less page files.

Having a clustered index, when it isnt used will also bear some overhead in updating/creating stats on a table and doing inserts (page splits)

So if you arent going to use the index, and aren't going to filter on your table you are better off without the index